# inherit from a class or use it as a component?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

For a college course I'm implementing a system of linear equations (and a way to solve it) in c++. This system consists of a (sparse) matrix and a vector. I've written an extra class to implement the matrix and provide some functions related to it (check if it is symmetric, multiply it with a vector, print it to stdout, etc.).

My question is as follows: Should my class "systemLinearEquations" inherit form the class "sparseMatrix" or should it have a component of the class "sparseMatrix"?

What are the benefits/drawbacks to do it either way?

Answer (score 4):

A linear equation is not a matrix, but rather it is represented as one. Typically in such cases you should prefer composition over inheritance.

Think of it like this: can someone threat my linear equation as if it is a matrix? Do all the matrix operations make sense for a linear equation? If the answer to both question is `yes` then probably the better choice is to inherit matrix, but otherwise you better use composition.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking inheritance satisfy generality, which means the base class provides common procedures while the child classes provide specific implementation (override) or extension of the basic behavior.

so it really depends what you are looking after...

Answer (score 1):

The most important criterion: public inheritance represents an **IS-A** relationship. In the following: `class Gadget : public Widget`, you're claiming that every `Gadget` **is a** `Widget` and can do anything a `Widget` can do. If an operation expects a `Widget` on input, it must work as normal when a `Gadget` is passed in.

These are the glasses you should put on when judging inheritance design. If a linear system can be used wherever a matrix can be used, and supports all operations which a matrix supports, then you can inheritance. Otherwise, you should favour composition.

I don't know the details of your particular task, but I would personally prefer composition here. A matrix will surely support a `transpose()` operation. What should that do with a linear system? If it's not square, you'll have trouble getting values for the right-hand sides, for example.